# Receiving Error for gnuplot when running system() in C++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, runtime, gnuplot

I am trying to write a simple C++ program to write data (hardcoded for now) to a file and then display the data as a chart using gnuplot which I have installed with brew on MacOS.

The following is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.dat");
  myfile << "0 0 0.001\n1 0.25 0.1\n2 0.5 0.05\n3 0.75 0.4";
  myfile.close();
  cout << "Successful Write to file.\n";
  system("gnuplot");
  //system("plot 'example.dat'");
  cout << "\nSuccessful Command Call.";
  return 0;
}
```

However, I receive the error:

```
sh: gnuplot: command not found
```

I would be grateful for any help on how to resolve this.

Comment: Is `gnuplot` in the `PATH`? If you attempt to run plain `gnuplot` from a shell (which is really what `system` is doing) does it work? Where is the `gnuplot` command installed? Perhaps you need to provide the full and absolute path to it?

Comment: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin is the path when I run cout << "PATH=" << getenv("PATH"); from the c++ program. However, I don't know where gnuplot is installed. How would I find that? gnuplot does run from the shell terminal, by the way. When I run gnuplot from the terminal I get the message Terminal type is now 'qt' and it runs fine. I hope this helps.

Comment: In your terminal where you can run `gnuplot`, run the command `echo $PATH`. Does it give the same result as from inside your program? Also what does the command `which gnuplot` report?

Comment: I have just found that /usr/local/bin/gnuplot is the path of gnuplot. That's which gnuplot. echo $PATH gives me something really long which I can't post. So, that's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have just substituted /usr/local/bin/gnuplot into gnuplot in C++ code at it seems to be working. Thank so much for your help!